# tmux copy mode freezes on a vagrant virtual machine session

Tags: ubuntu, tmux, vagrant

I use vagrant for having my development environment on Mac OSX and I use ubuntu within virtual machine for doing the development. I use tmux for multiple session, it works great on Mac OS iterm, but when I do a vagrant ssh to my linux machine. The tmux session there behaves wierdly for the copy mode only. It hangs on the copy mode, where the only thing I can do is kill the window. I am able to do copy/paste on screen in the same scenario, but tmux is where I observe the problem. As I can do copy-paste on tmux+mac, I know the correct keys and commands.

Could there be anything happening with this vagrant-on-mac+ssh+ubuntu+tmux setup which is causing this weird behavior? Any helpful suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Before starting tmux, try setting `EVENT_NOKQUEUE=1`.  That is, do one of:

```
$ export EVENT_NOKQUEUE=1
$ tmux
```

or

```
$ EVENT_NOKQUEUE=1 tmux
```

or

```
$ echo 'export EVENT_NOKQUEUE=1' >> ~/.bashrc
$ exec bash
$ tmux
```